# Is there a general purpose Java paint applet base?

Tags: java, applet, cbir

I'm working on a system for graphically querying data from a database of parasite specimens, in this case, these worm-like ones called [Trematodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trematoda).

Specifically, I'm looking at how to do the front end.  It needs to be web based, so I'm looking at using Java.

The way I envision it working is much like [Mr. Potato Head](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Potato_Head).  Users would select an outline of the body, and then drag and drop various pieces in, like testes, suckers, etc.

Does anyone know of a good starting point for this?  Are there any general purpose applets out there I could build onto, rather than having to write this from scratch?  Thanks.

**PS -- I'm not married to Java.  If something like this exists in another form, I can probably work with that too.  But I should point out I don't have access to any Flash dev tools.*

EDIT -- Based on the advice presented and skills I actually have at the moment, I've decided to go with a Javascript/Ajax type solution.  Google's Web Toolkit looks cool, but I think jQuery probably suits my needs a little better, particularly regarding Drag And Drop functionality. Thanks again.

Comment: Flex is a great language (or Flash toolkit, depending on who you ask) for this kind of thing.  Students and faculty can get Flex builder for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying Google Web Toolkit (GWT). You can create very sophisticated Java programs that run in the browser without a plugin.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/

You can see some amazing examples here:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/examples/
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/